# What data structure should I use for extracting frames contained in a frame?

Tags: java, html, data-structures

I need to extract all elements visible inside a scrolling panel. I have a long list of elements inside, and their positions respectively to the scrolling panel. I wish to retrieve all elements visible in O(1). I wondered what data structure I should use to store the list of elements, all I know is their relative positions inside the scrolling panel {top, bottom, left, right}.

code is in java (GWT for wep app)

[See drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujPs2.png)

Comment: if you know the number of  visible elements and their positions, use an array

Comment: What data structures have you considered? @akshayapandey don't be silly.

Comment: I made something sort of work, using 'top' position and sorting an array. But it feels like I could use some 2-Dimensional sorting kinda thing @Kayaman